# java.sql.SQLException The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a java/hibernate/jpa app that uses the following ojdbc driver (because of historical reasons, have to connect to an Oracle 10 DB). I am getting the following error message

> 2017-09-16 13:36:02 WARN  o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup - Unable to
>   determine jdbc url from datasource
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
>   get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Io
>   exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connect

Whenever I use the internal definition of the host (holding the DB - and not 127.0.0.1 loopback address), it works. Whenever I use the externally defined hostname, it does not work.

When using the **application.properties file** the following connect string *DOES WORK* for the APP:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**internalhost**:1527:DSM
>   (ex: 192.x.x.x - 192.88.33.22 ) Pls note, I am NOT using 127.0.0.1
>   (loopback address)

When using the **application.properties file** the following connect string *DOES NOT WORK* for the APP:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**externalhost.com**:1527:DSM
>   (ex: 99.22.123.44)

I run the following at the OS LEVEL - this test *DOES WORK* :

> sqlplus
>   scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=externalhost.com)(PORT=1527))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DSM)))

I ran the following Java test (at OS LEVEL) and it *DOES WORK*

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class OracleJDBCExample {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");
        try {
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            /*Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");*/

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@externalhost.com:1527:DSM", "scott", "tiger");              
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this problem?
TIA

**application.properties file**

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@externalhost.com\:1527\:DSM  (ex: 99.22.123.44)
spring.datasource.username=scott
spring.datasource.password=tiger
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

**Error received**

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2017-09-16 13:35:34 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-09-16 13:35:34 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-09-16 13:35:34 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-09-16 13:35:34 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-09-16 13:35:34 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2017-09-16 13:35:34 INFO  ccinfw.MainApplication - Starting MainApplication on kdclaptop with PID 17172 (C:\Users\dgmufasa\git\LocalCCINFieldworkServer\ccinfieldworkserver\target\classes started by dgmufasa in C:\Users\dgmufasa\git\LocalCCINFieldworkServer\ccinfieldworkserver)
2017-09-16 13:35:34 INFO  ccinfw.MainApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-09-16 13:35:35 INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@44616f65: startup date [Sat Sep 16 13:35:35 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-16 13:35:38 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [applicationConfigurationProperties]
2017-09-16 13:35:38 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Removing [applicationConfigurationProperties] PropertySource
2017-09-16 13:35:38 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Removing [defaultProperties] PropertySource
2017-09-16 13:35:39 INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-09-16 13:35:39 INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-09-16 13:35:39 INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-09-16 13:35:39 INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-09-16 13:35:39 DEBUG o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2017-09-16 13:35:39 INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root 

[...snip ...]

2017-09-16 13:35:39 INFO  o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 13:35:39 INFO  o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 13:35:40 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
2017-09-16 13:36:01 ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d97029fd.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d97029fd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be6e3771.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d97029fd.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at ccinfw.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:19)
2017-09-16 13:36:02 WARN  o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup - Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

**Update (took out pom.xml def)**

@Mark Rotteveel. Thanks for response SID = service-name. See below.

```
SQL> show parameter service
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
service_names                        string      DSM
```

Also, note:

```
WORKS (Hibernate is doing the connection):
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@internalhost:1527:DSM  
internalhost example (192.167.1.xxx)

DOES NOT WORK (Hibernate is doing the connection)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@externalhost.com:1527:DSM 
externalhost.com example (92.34.144.88)

DOES NOT WORK (Hibernate is doing the connection)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//externalhost.com:1527/DSM 
externalhost.com example (92.34.144.88)

TEST AT OS LEVEL DOES WORK ( using externalhost.com as a HOST )
sqlplus scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=externalhost.com)(PORT=1527))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DSM)))

TEST AT OS LEVEL USING **PLAIN JAVA CODE** - in other words NO Hibernate - DOES WORK ( using externalhost.com as a HOST )
(see above)
```

**How can one do a more detailed tracing?**

At first I thought it was a networking error - but - I am still able to connect to the DB using regular JAVA and also connecting at the OS level. Again, these work. It does not seem to work when doing it with the Hibernate connection.

However using Hibernate on internal (ex: 192.168.1.xxx) address works.
Using Hibernate for the exact same machine (but just using the external address - ex: 93.23.44.22 ) does not work.

Comment: The connection string you use is for connecting to SID, but you want to connect to a servicename instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - thx for answer. See response in "Update of message" ..

Comment: Having same problem.. did you get it to work?